# Python scatter plot: how to display times series from light to dark colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, time-series, scatter-plot

I would like to make a scatter plot showing its time series by its color evolution (e.g., light red to dar red), where I have three independent time series data.

[image]

The current code of drawing each time series is:

```
trj_up = open('./up_a_2.dat','r')
lines=trj_up.readlines()

xdata = []
for i in lines:
    xdata.append(float(i.split()[1]))

ydata = []
for i in lines:
    ydata.append(float(i.split()[2]))

print(xdata)
print(ydata)

plt.scatter(xdata,ydata,color='blue')
```

Each file contains the following time series (see below). What I want to do is changing their color from 150 to 185 with color evolutions from light red to dark red, light blue to dark blue, light green to dark green.

I hope that my explanation is clear enough.

```
150 -29.1207268 -27.2175614
 151 -30.0192526 -5.39084822
 152 -26.5683873 -12.0879794
 153 -23.9083554 -8.89568682
 154 -24.4077309 -7.38482774
 155 -30.0130369 -12.524116
 156 -25.5662431 -10.7311189
 157 -30.4412668 -6.75740378
 158 -34.4187745 -9.34580093
 159 -32.8574865 -7.13468933
 160 -29.3135992 -12.6535351
 161 -27.1047419 -10.032973
 162 -29.9819681 -11.5874607
 163 -29.5163317 -8.82843222
 164 -32.4836636 -8.84216924
 165 -34.8578521 -12.6671381
 166 -38.7623008 -16.6893051
 167 -40.6933921 -10.2265058
 168 -38.6141408 -14.5406604
 169 -39.4936256 -15.8318642
 170 -33.2624184 -20.9177089
 171 -36.4191314 -21.5573257
 172 -10.0391609 -17.7451025
 173 -30.9494031 -17.9689093
 174 -31.5509687 -15.1635098
 175 -32.2729627 -19.8517145
 176 -30.5633213 -22.5465021
 177 -32.3842971 -19.4456455
 178 17.1779354 -21.7972776
 179 15.4035048 -29.0108646
 180 -7.42574637 -21.591565
 181 -30.3152961 -18.2796513
 182 -32.394022 -19.8493851
 183 -35.4276138 -13.7519211
 184 -34.5321409 -13.5833979
 185 -31.9403951 -11.2472362
```

Answer (score 0):

`scatter` takes a `c` argument that can then be mapped into a colormap using the `cmap` argument

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html

Something like `ax.scatter(xdata, ydata, time, cmap='Reds')` should work, with perhaps some playing with the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments.